# How to avoid using @objc with a refresh control in iOS 11 with Swift 4?

Tags: ios, ios11, swift4, uirefreshcontrol

I upgraded my project from Swift 3 to Swift 4 and during the migration it inserted a bunch of '@objc' annotations in my code. I wish to get rid of them to avoid generating any Objective-C entry points. One of the ones I can't figure out how to get rid of, is using the refresh control. Here is the offending code:

```
let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyController.handleRefresh(refreshControl:)), for: .valueChanged)
self.table.refreshControl = refreshControl;
```

The problem is the use of the #selector it seems. How can I implement my refresh control without a selector?

Comment: *to avoid generating any Objective-C entry points* Why is this important to you?

Comment: @Caleb My main reason is that I want to write clean, beautiful Swift-4 code with no Objective-C in there, and the objc thing is ugly. My second reason is that apparently, "it is costly to generate all those Objective-C entry points" (http://evgenii.com/blog/disabling-swift3-objc-inference-in-xcode9/).

Comment: FWIW, the thing that actually changed between Swift 3 and Swift 4 in these cases is `@objc` is now explicit, rather than being implicit. The places where you were told to add them are places where they used to be added automatically by the compiler. So you're not _losing_ any performance by having them compared to Swift 3, but now you actually know _where_ it's happening in your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I wish to get rid of them

You can't, and you need to stop wanting to. `#selector` *is* an Objective-C feature and therefore you *must* explicitly expose the action method to Objective-C. (Previously you were already exposing it implicitly; now you must say what you mean.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@IBAction` instead of `@objc`
Both use reflection but Swift4 has no problem with `@IBAction`